# Produce nesting objects json response in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new comer in rails.I have two class story and scene. Story has_may scenes and scenes belong_to stories.When i call '/stories/1/scenes.json' then i want this output

"stories": [
        {

```
        "name": "akbar and bilber",
        "description": "some description", 
        "story_type": "simple",
        "state": "active",
        "scenes":{
                    "id":"1" 
                    "name": "Akber's introduction",
                    "description":"Akber is king"
                 },
                 {
                    "id":"2" 
                    "name": "bilber's introduction",
                    "description":"bilber's is consultant of akber"
                 },
       "created_at": "2013-09-22T16:32:41.050Z", 
       "updated_at": "2013-09-22T16:32:41.050Z", 
     }]
```

Here is models:

```
       class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
            has_many :scene
       end
       class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :story
      end
```

what i need to write in these controller and in show.json.jbulder file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this part in scenes action and you also need to use json library.

```
@story = Story.find(params[:id])
render :json => @story.scenes.to_json
```

And you have to correct your mistake in Story Model has_many should be plural not singular

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :scenes
end
```

Comment: It gives error that "Couldn't find Story without an ID".how to access stories's id in scenes controller? please tell me from strach.

Comment: What should i do for stories/1/scene/1.json to fetch single scene from story?

Comment: If you have created controller for scenes then url will be like this:
/scenes/1.json
In this case do this:
scene = Scene.find(params[:id])
render :json => scene.to_json

Comment: I think you're not getting my point.I want only one scene from particular story.eg. story is "hare and tortoise" with :story_id=1 and i want one scene with :id=4 of this hare and tortoise story.Then how will i get this? I have scene controller. But i want result of stories/:story_id/scenes/:id.json and This response should contain story name,story_id attributes also.